# May we illuminate scrolls?

Tags: megillat-esther, sefer-torah, art

Since the Middle Ages, it has become more common to find [illuminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminated_manuscript) megillot Esther: kosher scrolls of Esther with pictures around the text. Here is one example: [link](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/an-illuminated-megillah-judaic-treasures). I have seen such a megillat Esther in person, and I've also seen an illuminated megillat Shir HaShirim. However, I have never seen an illuminated sefer Torah.

I am looking for sources that discuss the (im)permissibility of illuminating kosher scrolls (intended for ritual use). I'd be especially interested in sources that distinguish between megillat Esther/the megillot and Torah/the rest of Tanakh.

**Note**: the sources should explicitly discuss illumination; I already know of discussions of writing in brachot/piyyutim for megillat Esther or adding nekudot to a sefer Torah/megillat Esther, and unless there's a direct logical link between those discussions and illumination, I'm looking for more.

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/32921322/Italian_Origins_of_the_Decorated_Scrolls_of_Esther An important historical factor in this question is when and where the practice began, since prior to that we wouldn't expect to find anyone discussing it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Even if we don't have any illuminated megillot from before the 16th century, manuscript illumination is old (and there are illuminated Jewish manuscripts older than the 16th century), so you could still hope to find an early discussion.

Comment: Strange that someone would downvote this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question.

The subject was discussed in a few places. A list of sources was brought in the book Yavoh Yedid, by Rabbi Shlomo Za'frani, pp. [128](https://beta.otzar.org/#/b/621065/p/158/t/1647603015919/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c/1647603028650)-[129](https://beta.otzar.org/#/b/621065/p/159/t/1647603015919/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c/1647603053417).

Here are some of the sources:

1. Eliyah Rabbah [siman 697:7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7767&st=&pgnum=438) discusses this and concludes that like in Sifrei Torah where drawing pictures is not allowed, in megillot it's lechatchilah not allowed:

> "אין לכתוב בדף כו' כ"כ ב"י בשם ראבי"ה וכמדומ' שנוהגין להקל לכת[בו?] שוב עיינ' בס' אמרכל שכתב דהפו' חולקי' על ראבי"ה דהא אמרי' שמא יאמרו ברכות כתובות בתורה בין פ' לפ' אבל אי כתב בתחלתס"ת או בסוף אין לפסול ע"י. א"כ במגילה אפשר דאפי לכתחלה מותר ומ"מ טוב לחוש לכתחלה ונראה דגם הציורים שעושין בגליונת אינו נכון דהא לכתחלה בעינן כמו ס"ת ובס"ת פשיט/ דאסור גם דמי למ"ש סי' צ' סק"נ דאסור לצור ציורים בספרים שמתפללי/ מיהו בזה יש לחלק דבתפלה בעינן לכוונה ביותר."

2. ShU"T Zerah Emet who discusses this in [Pt 1, siman 100](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28684&pgnum=41) (right side of the page):

> "...ונראה שגם בציורים שעושים בגליונות אינו נכון דלכתחלה בעינן כס"ת ובס"ת פשיטא דאסור ע"כ הרי דכללא כייל לן הרב בקבא רבה דכל מה שאינו פוסל בס"ת מותר לעשות במגילה לכתחילה ואע"פ שסיים ומ"מ טוב לחוש לכתחילה לא כתב זה אלא על צד היותר טוב משום דהויא מילתא בפלוגתא בין ראבי"ה לס' אמרכל דהיא מחלוקת שקולה אבל כנ"ד נר' ודאי דקי"ל בהרמב"ם ודעימיה דאפי' בס"ת אינו פוסל בכה"ג וא"כ ממילא נר' דא"צ ליזהר במגילה אפי' לכתחילה ואפי' ע"צ היותר טוב נר' דא"צ ליזהר דודאי א"ז מחלוקת שקול דרבו החולקים על הנ"י דפוסל בדיעבד בס"ת ובפרט דאפי' הנ"י לא כתב דפסול אלא בסיים לעיני כל ישראל בסוף שיטה משום לישנא דרב אשי דאמר באמצע שיטה דוקא ומלישנא דדוקא משמע ליה דפסול בדעיבד והנ"ל אבל בסיים באמצע הדף דליכ' האי דיוק' אה"נ דאף הנ"י קאזיל ומודה דבדיעבד כשר אפי' לגבי ס"ת וממילא לגבי מגילה יהיה מותר אפילו לכתחיל' וכנ"ל."

I don't know if I understood exactly what he wrote about Sifrei Torah, but the gist of what he says seems to be that illuminating Torah scrolls is disputed and any issue that is disputed in the laws of writing Torah scrolls is lechatchila allowed in the case of writing megillot.

Then later on he [writes](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28684&pgnum=41) (bottom left of the page):

> "...ותדע שהרי מנהגנו שלא ליזהר מלעשות ציורים ופיתחים סביב המגילה והרבה עושים כן ומכוונים להיות ליפוי המגילה אע"פ שבס"ת אסור לעשות כן..."

3. Another source is ShU"T Rivevot Efraim, Vol. 6, [siman 427](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1084&pgnum=535) (it's long so I won't copy it) where he writes that it's not allowed. He discusses the issue of Sifrei Torah as well.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that all of these take for granted/as obvious the איסור to illuminate a Torah? Also, who's נ״י in the zera avraham?

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. I have no idea who the נ"י is, but it was a little difficult to read the print. It's an old book. I might have misread.

Comment: I read it inside and I also read נ״י. Apparently there's a newer edition, but I don't see it online.

Comment: Source #2 is really discussing ending the last column in the middle of page instead of on the bottom row, or on the bottom row but all the way at the end of the row. I don't believe that it's saying that illuminating a Torah is disputed.

Comment: @magicker72 Nimmukei Yosef https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37966&st=&pgnum=754

Comment: @DoubleAA What are you pointing me to? I didn't see anything in the nimmukei yosef there.

Comment: @magicker72 That's נ״י see three lines from the bottom

Comment: @DoubleAA OH thank you. :-) You can delete the last three comments if you clarify נ״י = nimmukei yosef in your previous one.

Comment: @DoubleAA I second the shkoyech.